# arecord through subprocess works randomly in raspberry pi，how to solve？

Tags: python, pi-2, audio

I am using arecord through subprocess to record in raspberry pi : press joystick button to start recording and press button again to stop recording, It works randomly: when I press the button, the background picture changes successfully but sometimes it couldn't record. really strange to me.

```
 #detect button press
 if joystick.get_numbuttons() >= 1 and joystick.get_button( 0 ) == 0 and button_pressed:
button_pressed = False
is_recording = not is_recording
print(is_recording)

#start recording
if is_recording:
    dotting = dotting + 1
    #recording code
   datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    filename = "%s.wav" % datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    p=subprocess.Popen(['arecord', '--device=hw:1,0', '--format', 'S16_LE', '--rate', '44100-c1', filename], shell=False)

    #change background
    background = pygame.image.load(background_image2).convert()
    #start timer
    stopFlag = Event()
    timer = MyTimer(stopFlag,time.clock())
    #timer.start()
    text2 = font.render('.', True, BLACK)

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    stopFlag.set()

    #record, remaining here


#stop recording
else:
    #stop recording, save record

    #back to previous question
    timer.do_run = False
    backToPreviousQuestion()
    background = pygame.image.load(background_image).convert()
    #kill console
    #os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM
    p.terminate()
 pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: `arecord` could be reporting an error, but since you're not capturing stdout, stderr, or the return code it's hard to tell what it is. Try capturing those in Python and printing out each time and update your post with that info.

If arecord always returns a success code and isn't printing an error, check `dmesg` for errors as well.

Comment: thanks, i am really a noob in programming and python, I googled "stdout" and "stderr" and find https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/09/how-get-stdout-and-stderr-using-python-subprocess-module/ which talks about how stdout and stderr works .  I will this first. much thanks.